# What does "steal my crown" mean in Kacey Musgraves's Butterflies?

Tags: meaning, song-lyrics

I was enjoying a song "Butterflies" by Kacey Musgraves and in the lyrics there is "Stealing my heart 'stead of stealing my crown".
What does "steal my crown" mean? I am not a native English speaker, and I think that not anybody has a crown to steal, unless he is a king. So why does it say "steal my crown"?

Comment: It doesn't make much sense. It's more to rhyme with "down".

Comment: "and while the king was looking down
the jester stole his thorny crown" — *American Pie,* by Don McLean.

Answer (score 5):

The song's lyrics include these lines:

> Now you're liftin' me up, 'stead of holdin' me down
> Stealin' my heart, 'stead of stealin' my crown
> Untangled all the strings, round my wings, that were tied
> ...
> Now I remember what it feels like to fly

Just as the singer isn't a queen to have a crown, she isn't likely to have wings and be able to fly either. Those are metaphors.

The singer says that before she met the person she has fallen in love with, people would steal her crown rather than her heart. To *steal someone's heart* means to have them fall in love with you. But to steal a crown means to usurp power that isn't rightfully yours from the legitimate king or queen.

This means that the singer says that the man she is in love with has treated her with respect, unlike the people she has been around before. Stealing her crown means that they never let her feel powerful; instead, they took away the power she should have had. They have held her down, i.e., made her powerless.

Similarly, her wings represent her freedom. Earlier, she had strings tied around her wings, meaning that her freedom was taken away. The man she is in love with makes her feel powerful and free by not stealing her crown and by disentangling the strings that tied down her wings.